# React's state update vs ref async update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React's state update is **async** and that's why you should not try to use the **state** (like **logging** or **any other reading operation**) just after setting it. But only **async** keyword seems to not give the total picture of how React updates the state.

How is this **state** update different from a **ref** update done asynchronously ?

Consider the following snippet where we simulate **async** updation of `statefulRef`. Even after we update the `statefulRef` **asynchronously**, if we access it after the update, we will get the latest value. But the same is not true with `state`. I know that both **render** and **closure** take part in explaining this `state` update but I would like to have a detailed answer explaining the differences of **async** behavior that we see below :-

```js
const {
  useState,
  useRef
} = React

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({current:0});
  const statefulRef = useRef(0);

  function updateState() {
    // below is async operation
    setState({current:state.current + 1});
    // below is async logging
    setTimeout(() => console.log("React state : ",state.current), 500);
  }

  function updateRef() {
    // below is async operation
    setTimeout(() => statefulRef.current += 1, 200);
    // below is async logging
    setTimeout(() => console.log("React ref : ",statefulRef.current), 500);
  }

  return ( 
    <div >
    <button onClick = {updateState}> Update State </button> 
    <button onClick = {updateRef}> Update Ref </button> 
    </div>
  )

}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Long story short, state closure is the reason for this behavior. https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/ The reason the console shows the outdated value of `state` is because the callback passed to `setTimeout` is referencing an outdated value of `state` captured by the closure.

Comment: @codemonkey So can we say that the react's `state` update is not **time-bound** but **render-bound** i.e. only in the new render you would be able to access the new state. It doesn't matter how long the **wait time** you mention in the **timer**, it will always holds the **stale closed over** `state` from **previous render** ?

Comment: Absolutely. That `setTimeout` can wait a week for all it cares and it will still reference the old value. The `statefulRef` variable, on the other hand, is not constrained by the closure mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

`state` is captured at the moment the program execution enters the `updateState` function. So the `console.log` will show an outdated value with or without the `setTimeout`.

Same is true for `statefulRef`, it's captured when the execution of `updateRef` begins. But `statefulRef` is an object and in JavaScript objects are references. What is captured is the reference, not the value (the values of the properties). So, even though `statefulRef` will not change, `statefulRef.current` may. Whereas with `state` things work more or less like this:

```js
function updateRef() {
    const current = statefulRef.current;
    // below is async operation
    setTimeout(() => (statefulRef.current += 1), 200);
    // below is async logging
    setTimeout(() => console.log("React ref : ", current), 500);
}
```

**UPDATE:** The fact that `state` itself is an object (as in the updated question), doesn't change much. `setState` replaces the old value with a new one, it doesn't assign to `state`'s properties without changing `state` itself. You could achieve something similar by doing `state.current = 1` but you shouldn't because it would break React's assumptions about state management.

Comment: Updated the post with `state` as object.

Comment: It doesn't change anything. `setState` changes the whole state, not it's contents. I'll update the answer.